# Does $A$ only if $B$ cover the case $A$ is false, $B$ is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am studying Automata theory and in its introduction , there is a statement about conditionals,
if A then B  is logically equivalent to A only if B.
But if B is true and A is false , then if A then B holds true.
Then, what about A only if B ?
Will it also be true?

Comment: This is possible since $B$ is only a necessary , but not necessarily a sufficient condition for $A$.

Comment: In fact, "$A\implies B$" is equivalent to "A only if B"

Comment: @Peter So am i right in saying that B is required for A to be true , but it can also depend on other factors ?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider: "Pat is a bachelor only if Pat is male"

I hope that you agree that this is a true statement: one can be a bachelor only if one is male.

But note, it is perfectly possible for Pat to be a male but not a bachelor (simply because Pat is married).

So with:

$A$: Pat is a bachelor

$B$: Pat is male

we would have:

$B$ is True

$A$ is False

$A$ only if $B$ is True